# Wordpress swift builder framework carousel arrows split

Tags: swift, wordpress, carousel

I have a wordpress site made by Swift builder framework. I have an portfolio carousel there, but the carousel arrow buttons are generated automatically. Is it possible to split buttons, that prev button will be on left and right button will be on right? Thank you

Comment: Please share your site URL so that I can check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can hide it by adding the following CSS in  **"Appearance - > Customize -> Additional CSS”**

```html
#slider-nav { display: none; }
```

Comment: Hey, I don't want to HIDE buttons. I need left button float left and right button float right. There must be an captation <h3> between them. That's a problem.

Comment: share with me screenshot or site url otherwise  I can't help on that